# JqGrid view-column in editGridRow-mode

Tags: jqgrid

is there a way to define a column in modalDialog as view-column (without any input elements, neither editable nor saveble)? Or does it work only through `edittype:'custom'`?

My setup is there:

http://babiychuk.com/demo/en/catalog/index/c_picture

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid use `$.jgrid.createEl` method to build elements for any types of editing inclusive [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing) (the function [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow)). How you can see in [the source code of the function createEl](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.common.js#L256) it use `<input>`, `<select>`, `<button>`, `<textarea>` or `<span>` elements for the "input" part of the form dialog. The choose depend on the [edittype](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#edittype) of the corresponding jqGrid column.

So you have to either to use [edittype:'custom'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom) to have `<span>` element or you can try to modify form elements inside of your [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) event handler.

Comment: I done it with edittype:'custom' with the function `'custom_element' => "function(value, options) {return '<span>'+value+'</span>';}",` Is it the best way to do that? What I don't like here, is that the span-element is rendered twice. I tried to use the already existing span, but I have not suceeded.

Comment: @Anatoliy: It is a misunderstanding. You asked about the HTML elements included in the edit form dialogs. If you double click on any row from your demo http://babiychuk.com/demo/en/catalog/index/c_picture to open the Edit dialog you can examine it's contain with Internet Explorer developer tools. The same you can do in the Google Chrome with the integrated developer tools or in Firefox using Firebug. Independend on the tools which you use you will see that the data for the "rating" element **are already placed** inside the `<span class="FormElement">...</span>`. So you don't need it yourself.

Comment: @Anatoliy: The most other elements are placed inside of `<input>` element. So if you want not have `<input>` element you can just use any implementation of the `edittype:'custom'`.

Comment: Sorry, i did not mentioned that I am talking about cell "Code". If you look inside of cell "code", you will find the span element twice. I hate redundancy. The issue with rating is closed for me so far - it is good working condition. PS. I already work with firebug ;).