# jqgrid 2 span elements within one custom cell?

Tags: jqgrid

Within my custom cell there are 2 span-elements.

```
<span class="FormElement">
    <span class="customelement" id="code" name="code">BER01_CN_045_002</span>
</span>
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

See the [demo](http://babiychuk.com/demo/en/catalog/index/c_picture), I am talking about cell "code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that you should don't spend your time in such kind of code optimization. Like I tried to explain in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867403/jqgrid-view-column-in-editgridrow-mode) the first `<span>` will be inserted by jqGrid for all form elements having the option [edittype:'custom'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom). The second `<span>` you inserted yourself in the code of your custom formatter. It is permitted to have nested `<span>` elements like to have nested `<div>` elements. I recommend you better to follows the jqGrid standard code as trying to make any kind of optimization which nobody will see at the end except you.

Moreover if you look more in the HTML code of your page generated by jqGrid you will see that the form itself (the form with id="FrmGrid_grid" in your example) are placed inside of `<span>`. In the same way in the code of the column headers you will also find `<span class="s-ico">` which has another two `<span>` elements as the children. Would you like to try to "optimize" also the code? So I repeat my advice just to hold jqGrid standards and not trying to optimize such small pieces of code like nested `<span>` elements.

Comment: Hmmm. I am trying to develope without redundancy, but you are right, sometimes it is very time-consuming and obviously in this case not easy to implement.

Comment: @Anatoliy: Sorry for the answer, but we all have to stay pragmatic. jqGrid want be sure that the data will have class="FormElement". You have to get the data id="code" so you have an HTML element like `<span>` to use the id. So I really see here no problem.

Comment: @Oleg: If you look at the problem html(or xhtml)-specific, there is no need to have 2 span-elements in such situations. We have `<td class="DataTD">&nbsp;<span class="FormElement"><span class="customelement" id="code" name="code">BER01_CN_045_002</span></span></td>` and it would be enough to have `<td class="DataTD"><span class="FormElement" id="code"> name="code">BER01_CN_045_002</span></td>`. My principle is as much HTML as needed and not as much as possible.

Comment: @Anatoliy: You should not forget about the existing interface of the `custom_element`. It must return an element (as text or as DOM). If you look at the code https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.common.js#L437you will see that the element returned by the `custom_element` function will be expanded with the attributes `class="FormElement" id="code"`. Then the parent `<span>` element will be appended with it. So with existing code of jqGrid you **unable** to create the HTML code `<td class="DataTD"><span class="FormElement" id="code"> name="code">BER01_CN_045_002</span></td>`.

Comment: @Oleg: I trust your experience and your knowledge. So I live it as it is. I am always very curious about your feedback. Thanks.